# Find sequence between elements in a vector

Tags: r

I would like to get the sequence between elements in a vector. Here is a reproducible example.

```
vec <- c( 'a', letters[2:7], 'a', letters[9:14], 'a', letters[16:21] ) # sample data
ind_a <- which( grepl( 'a', vec ))  # indices matching the character 'a'
ind_a <- c( ind_a, length(vec)+1 )  # concatenate the length of 'vec' + 1 with indices
ind_a
# [1]  1  8 15 22
```

Now, how to compute the sequence between the elements of `ind_a`. For example, `seq(from = 2, to = 7, by = 1)` and the same for others.

Preferably, I would like to know any function in base R for this task.

**Expected Output**

```
# List of 3
# $ : int [1:6] 2 3 4 5 6 7
# $ : int [1:6] 9 10 11 12 13 14
# $ : int [1:6] 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create two vectors from 'ind_a' by removing the last and first observations, then get the sequence of corresponding elements with `Map`

```
Map(seq, ind_a[-length(ind_a)]+1, ind_a[-1]-1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

#[[2]]
#[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14

#[[3]]
#[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Or as @Zelazny7 suggested, removing the first and last element can be done with `head` and `tail` function

```
Map(`:`, head(ind_a, -1) + 1, tail(ind_a, -1) - 1)
```

Comment: Alternative syntax: `Map(seq, head(ind_a, -1) + 1, tail(ind_a, -1) - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(2:length(ind_a), function(i) setdiff(sequence(ind_a[i] - 1), sequence(ind_a[i-1])))
#OR    
lapply(2:length(ind_a), function(i) (ind_a[i-1]+1):(ind_a[i]-1))

#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

#[[2]]
#[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14

#[[3]]
#[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21
```